# Reporting services subreport column sorting failing

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reporting, service, subreport

I am working on a `SSRS 2008` reporting solution and I am running into a problem with a subreport not interactively sorting columns with the asp.net report viewer control. The report itself is completely functional when it is not used as a subreport, but once I add it to another report as a subreport you cannot sort the columns without getting an

> Error: Subreport could not be shown

The `ExecutionLog2` shows that the parent report receives the sort action request and the it says the sort status is successful. However, the byte and row count response are zero and the subsequent render report action is successful but only 590 bytes.

I am curious if anyone is aware of a known issue with `SSRS 2008` or if there are any known workarounds besides adding the report to the parent report.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that subreports only call their OnInit function during the first render...not during subsequent requests(sorts, paging, ect..) therefore my column visibility logic is failing. Doesn't appear to be a work around...